# Google nodejs client library return empty account list

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-tag-manager, google-client, google-tag-manager-server-side

What I am trying to do is using google api nodeJs client library to list accounts at my google tag manger using service key json file every thing works but I got an empty accounts, however I have one account, I tries several things but can't figure out what's wrong

This my code:

```
import { google, Auth } from "googleapis";
import * as path from "path";

const SCOPES = [
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/tagmanager.edit.containers",
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/tagmanager.readonly",
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/tagmanager.manage.accounts",
];

const main = async () => {
  try {
    const tagManager = await initTagManagerObject();

    const accounts = await tagManager.accounts.list({
      pageToken: "dummy",
    });

    console.log("accounts", accounts.data); // prints {}
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("error", error);
  }
};

const initTagManagerObject = async () => {
  const serviceAuth = new Auth.GoogleAuth({
    keyFile: path.join(__dirname, "../tag-manager-360107-9b3448dfc173.json"),
    // Scopes can be specified either as an array or as a single, space-delimited string.
    scopes: SCOPES.join(" "),
  });

  console.log(
    "ff",
    path.join(__dirname, "../tag-manager-360107-9b3448dfc173.json")
  );

  const client = await serviceAuth.getClient();

  const tagManager = await google.tagmanager({
    version: "v2",
    auth: client,
  });

  return tagManager;
};

main();
```

This is service key json file format

```
{
  "type": string,
  "project_id": string,
  "private_key_id": string,
  "private_key": string,
  "client_email": string,
  "client_id": string,
  "auth_uri": string,
  "token_uri": string,
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": string,
  "client_x509_cert_url": string,
}
```

here's screen shot of my service key

[image]

Please help me in this and thanks in advance

Comment: note that I already activate google tag api